# Богадельня: этимология и написание

Tags: этимология, орфография

У меня сразу два вопроса по одному слову — "богадельня". Во-первых, как я понимаю, изначально это было благотворительное учреждение для малоимущих и т.д., так почему же оно стало синонимом убожества? А во-вторых, почему "богАдельня", а как же соединительная О?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Богадельня писалась через ять: *богадѣльня*, что исключяает всякую связь с предлогом.
Богаде́льня (от слов Бога дѣля, то есть ради Бога)  (Вики)

Тут речь идет о *делении (разделении)* бога. Такая форма (делить, разделять кого) означала *делать что-то ради этого "кого", во имя него*. Близкое по смыслу - "богоугодничать", а по форме (но немного с другим смыслом) - "христарадничать".

Убожество же в значении *нищета, бедность* вполне стыкуется с понятием богадельни - как учреждения для неимущих. Другое дело, что это значение "убожества" тоже вторичное, но очень древнее. В нем прослеживается древнейшая отрицательная приставка (частица?) u-, в дословном переводе убогий - "не божий".

Таким образом, получаем интересный факт: в паре богадельня - убожество сошлись два противоположных отношения Бога и к Богу.

ЗЫ плюс - за подмеченную связь убожества и богадельни. 
///------------- 
С "делать", я ошибся. Тоже через ять. Но это ничего не меняет по сути.    
///------------- 
Добавление для IrinaGLA 
Я не считаю, что вопрос об исходной форме для дѣля актуален в данной теме. Я не вижу предмета спора. Да, мне не нравится прямое возведение к этой форме по причинам, которые я высказал. Не понимаю и то, зачем надо отстаивать именно "для" вопреки гораздо более естественному (и по мнению моих оппонентов - еще и родственному!) делить, разделять, я не понимаю. Другое дело, если бы я отстаивал "делать". Но этого нет и не было. 
Но! Все это - не по теме. Вопрос стоит: 
а) о правописании (почему там соединительная не О) - этого я до конца не заню и никто не ответил, 
б) общности с убожеством - тут вроде разобрались И хотя Ларf возводит убожество к совсем уже "доисторическому" Бог=богатство, в чем я крепко сомневаюсь, это опять-таки уже за рамками темы.
в) этимологии, точнее к частному вопросу, ошибочности возведения "...дельня" к делать. Тут тоже все в общем-то сошлись, кроме, разве, совсем уж частного момента "кощунственности", отстаиваемой Марком Изом и - к моему удивлению - Людмилой. Возможно, они сводят "делать Бога" к "сотворить кумира", возможно еще что-то, я аргументацию их не понимаю и кощунственности никакой не вижу. Но все это, как сказал, частности из частностей. А по сути - все согласны, что "делать Бога" в любом значении тут не прокатит. В отношении же деля=для во второй составляющей "богадельни" уже высказался. Мне не нравится, но это не предмет для ломания копий в этой теме.  
///-------------    
Добавление для Марк Из.

> Попробую объяснить, хоть и знаю, что впустую.

Марк Из, действительно, здесь и сейчас не стоит. Или хотя бы комментируйте под своим ответом, коли уж так приспичило. Изложите, подобно мне я, тезисно мои мысли, как их поняли, - и вперед с критикой. По крайней мере станет ясно, кто и с какими химерами воюет. Это просто просьба, не самомодерация. Ничего ***нового*** Вы не скажете, а здесь я просто высказал свое мнение, в отношении которого Вы уже весьма недвусмысленно и не раз высказывались. Зачем пожар раздувать? Я полагаю, Ирина сама разберется.

> согласен с вами, что это не менее кощунственно, чем "Бога делать".

Не приплетайте сюда меня, пожалуйста. Я такого не говорил.

> Кроме того, против вашей версии

Не знаю, о какой ***моей*** версии Вы говорите.

Это все.

//-----------------------------

Братцы-модераторы, ну может не стоит все-таки "принимать" вопрос в самый разгар "драки"? Пусть и ушедшей далеко в сторону от исходной темы?
Тем более, что вопрос с соединительной гласной у меня вообще не изложен. Никак. Ибо неясно.

Comment: >Но Ленскій, не имѣвъ конечно

 >Охоты узы брака несть,

 >Съ Онѣгинымъ желалъ сердечно

 >Знакомство покороче свесть.

 >Они сошлись: волна и камень,

 >Стихи и проза, ледъ и пламень

 >Не столь различны межъ собой.

 >Сперва взаимной разнотой

 >Они друтъ другу были скучны;

 >Потомъ понравились; потомъ

 >Съѣзжались каждый день верхомъ,

 >И скоро стали неразлучны.

 >Такъ люди — первый каюсь я —

 >**Отъ дѣлать нечего — друзья.**

Минус вам за непроверенные сведения!)))))))

Comment: Я думала, христорадный пишется через О.  
С ятем - не поняла. Если богадельня - очень древнее слово, то почему невозможно от дhля=для?

Comment: Все возможно! Бога радьма и Бога дельма...

Comment: irinaGLA, не совсем так. Я не утвеждаю древность богадельни, скорее всего как раз относительно молодое.  Древнее это убожество.
Я не очень хочу здесь и сейчас отвечать, обстановка не располагает.
Надеюсь, Вы понимаете. Мой адрес Вы знаете.

Comment: Хорошо. Спасибо. Ответ поняла.

Comment: irinaGLA, я несколько оптимистичнее стал смотреть на будущее на этом ресурсе. Так что можем продолжить. Только прежде всего выскажусь предельно тезисно. Я не считаю, что вопрос об исходной форме для дѣля актуален в данной теме. Я не вижу предмета спора. Мне не нравится прямое возведение к этой форму по причинам, которые я высказал. Зачем надо отстаивать именно "для" вопреки гораздо более естественному (и по мнению моих оппонентов - еще и родственному!) делить, разделять, я не понимаю. Другое дело, если бы я отстаивал "делать". Но этого нет и не было.     
Христорадный - так и только так.

Comment: >Зачем надо отстаивать именно "для" вопреки гораздо более естественному (и по мнению моих оппонентов - еще и родственному!) делить, разделять, я не понимаю.

Попробую объяснить, хоть и знаю, что впустую. Делить Бога вовсе не естественно, и согласен с вами, что это не менее кощунственно, чем "Бога делать". Кроме того, против вашей версии говорит ударение на "е" (от делить ударение скорей было бы на окончании), форма "бог**а**..", а не "бог*у*.." (делим Богу), или "бог*о*..", ну и, образованное по тому же принципу слово "христарадничать" (от Христа ради). Поэтому ваша версия и кажется надуманой

Comment: Марк Из, спасибо.   
behemothus, спасибо. Хотелось бы попроще и побольше позитива. Пишите о том, что стоит обсуждать, а не о том, что не стоит. Я же в Ваших стрелках все равно ничего не понимаю, мне просто интересно. Согласна, "ахронизм", как Вы его назвали, надо как-то объяснить. Но может просто слово не такое молодое? Марк Из этого не объяснил никак.

Comment: @irinaGLA, как я понял Марка Иза, наличие "дѣлѦ" в ЦСЯ исключает всякий анахронизм, слово могли заимствовать оттуда в любой момент.

Answer (score 6):

Богадельня произошла не от кощунственных "Бога делать", а от "Бога деля (для)" этим и объясняется написание **без** соединительной гласной.

Как синоним убожества, мне слово "богадельня" не попадалось. Иронически богадельнями называют организацию работы, при которой наличествуют бездеятельные или неспособные к данной деятельности люди. Почему появилось такое значение, объяснять вроде излишне, данные люди получают зарплату будто благотворительную помощь, своей деятельностью не окупая заработок.

Comment: Как синоним убожества, мне слово "богадельня" не попадалось  
    
А какое еще может быть переносное значение у богадельни? Только убогое. Про людей неспособных - что-то надуманное. Хотя одно другому не противоречит. Но мне тоже очень интресна Ваша трактовка "дельня" как производное от "для". Я правильно понимаю, что форма с "ять" - очень древняя? Тогда такое объяснение богадельни - или ахронизм явный или нужно какое-то разумное объяснение.

Comment: @irinaGLA, переносное значение мне встречавшее есть в ответе. Было бы логично, чтобы у богадельни было значение "убожество", но мне такового не попадалось на практике.

**ДѣлѦ** [деля] - это "для" на церковно-славянском, (подайте) "Бога дѣлѦ - стандартная фраза нищего. [Ссылка на словарь](http://www.orthodic.org/?searchCs=&searchRu=%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F&go.x=-847&go.y=-229&type=ru).

Comment: Хорошо. Спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

Согласна с МаркИзом : бога+для = БОГАДЕЛЬНЯ. По этимол. словарю: искон. суф. производное на базе (подайте) бога деля - "ради бога", ср. христарадничать "попрошайничать". Буквально "благотворительное заведение для нищих". (См. бог, для). [БОГАДЕЛЬНЯ](http://rokovila.lt/?p=51#more-51)

[для](http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F)

Для- происходит от др.-русск. дѣля (часто); ср.: ст.-слав. дѣлıа (др.-греч. διά), укр. дíля, белор. дзеле. Сокращение проведено уже в отдельных языках в безударном положении; независимо осуществилось оно в чешск. dle, словацк. dl’a, польск. dla. Отсутствие связи с дѣля ввиду тождества знач. невероятно. Использованы данные словаря М. Фасмера.

А вот нищий, убогий - от слова "бог" в древнем значении, ещё нерелигиозном - "богатство, изобилие". 
 У =не.  Убогий-"лишённый изобилия", а не "не божий".Убогий=Недееспособный потом появилось, позже, как переносное знач.

Comment: Людмила, о каком "древнем значении" может идти речь? 
Бог стал богом, божеством на праславянском уровне. 
А если уж копать в глубь веков, то возводите к значению "доля", "делить", от какового и произошло бог = "богатство". 
Вопрос о происхождении, кстати, весьма слова спорен. Возможно и заимствование. 
см. тут: [Бог](http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%BE%D0%B3)

Впрочем это все равно ничего не меняет по сути. 

Касательно Фасмера. Как могло произойти "сокращения" ятя (не ера!) - да еще параллельно во всех языках? Не верю, простите.

Comment: Кстати, М.И. ведь доказывает кощунственность предположения "делать бога". 
Чем это лучше  предположения о дѣля Бога в Вашем понимании? Если уж в слове для сохранилось якобы древнейшее написание ("дѣля")?    
Ко всему прочему еще и ахронизм великий получается.

Comment: Что-то о заимствовании в Вашей ссылке ничего нет. Вы имеете в виду церковно-славянский?Но это о вторичном значении, церковном.Первоначальное знач.(праиндоевроп.) было связано с обыденной жизнью и значило"достояние", "богатство"- хозяин-владыка-податель благ. Отсюда боги-идолы, отсюда и вторичное церковное. Насчёт сокращений - они были, помню по историч. грамматике.Исчезали не только редуцированные, но это Вы спорьте с Фасмером - его мнение, я не берусь его оспаривать.

Comment: По ссылке - это про исходное значение "делить", "доля".  
Про заимствование - это я про родство с иранскими и авестинскими, сейчас посмотрю содержательную ссылку.    
Но заимствование в моем комментарии - вещь глубоко вторичное. 
Суть моего недоверия к Вашей идее - в значении "делить", "доля", которое и породило ***позднейшее*** "богатый".
Это-то то Вы никак не прокомментировали.  
  
>Вы спорьте с Фасмером - его мнение, я не берусь его оспаривать.     
    
Да Бог с ним пока, С Фасмером. Хотя и на него компромат найдется.   
Объясните, как попала нередуцированная форма в современное слово:

Comment: Доказывает он не кощунственность "делать бога", хотя это действительно кощунственно: это Он нас "сделал", а не мы его.Посмотрите этимологию "для"-ему родственны делить, доля.В др.-р. уже писалось и с ятем, и без него и означало "для, ради, благодаря". В праслав.форма аблятива(отложительного)со знач."со стороны""что касается стороны"-через-причина, цель- предлог. Дѣль-часть в отношении к разделу.Др.-р.дѣлъ-часть, доля-борозда, межа, предел.В лат.аналогично: causa-причина, предлог,цель, для.

Comment: >он не кощунственность "делать бога",  
  
Там вроде недвусмысленно. А Ваше объяснение только путает. 
Я-то рассчитывал получить от Вас комментарий по применению аналогичного "кощунственного" подхода к Вашей версии, коли Вы уж с М.И. согласны. Если "для"="деля", то разве делить Бога менее кощунственно?     
Ну да Бог с ним. Разговор явно ушел в спор спелого с глухим. 

*Я беру тайм-аут просто из соображений нежелания доводить обстановку до пожара.*

Answer (score 0):

Богадельня - божье дело, дела Бога, т.е.благотворительность.